# Не изменяется переменная в другом проекте

Tags: c#

Я сделал два проекта. В одном из них я сделал класс, представляющий собой shared memory - class Data.Из клиента я меняю в нем переменную data,но когда мой сервер проверяет эту строку, она почему-то равна null, в результате чего выходит исключение. Она же видна в проекте Task8(1),почему же он не меняет ее? Скрин со структурой проекта приложил

Task8.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    namespace Task8
    {
        public class Data
        {
            public static String data;
            public static List<string> figures;
        }
        public class Task8
        {
            private Semaphore semaphore;
            static HttpListener server1 = new();
            static HttpListener server2 = new();
            public Task8()
            {
                server1 = new();
                server2 = new();
            }
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Server started");
                server1.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
                server1.Start();
                 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                  {
                      Process process = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Максим\\source\\repos\\Os_Lab4\\Task8(1)\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Task8(1).exe");
                 }
                Draw(server1);
            }
            public static void Draw(HttpListener server)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                while (true)
                {
                    string[] line = Data.data.Split();
                    int x, y, x1, y1;
                    int.TryParse(line[0], out x);
                    int.TryParse(line[1], out y);
                    int.TryParse(line[2], out x1);
                    int.TryParse(line[3], out y1);
                    string width = Math.Abs(x1 - x) + "";
                    string height = Math.Abs(y1 - y) + "";
                    string color = line[4];
                    string rect = "<svg>\r\n    <rect x=\"" + line[0] + "\" y=\"" + line[1] + "\" width=\"" + width + "\" height=\"" + height + "\"/>\r\n</svg>";
                    //     Data.figures.Add(rect);
                    string html = "<HTML><BODY>" + rect + "</BODY></HTML>";
                    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
                    // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    // You must close the output stream.
                    output.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                    //  Data.data = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Task8(1).cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Task8;

namespace Task8 {

 
    public class Client
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Client
           
                Console.WriteLine("Client");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter angles coordinates and color");
                Data.data = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(Data.data);
            
        }
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какую переменную менять должно, мы должны догадаться в этой каше самостоятельно, да? В любом случае, у вас пишет в окне вывода, что была ошибка `nullreferenceexception`, ставьте точки остановки и смотрите где конкретно была ошибка.

Comment: я же написал, что переменная data.Ошибка возникает в строке `string[] line = Data.data.Split();`. Но это как раз таки потому, что data null. Выходит в  клиенте в нее не записалось значение, как будто она readonly,хотя это не так

Comment: Я не вижу в коде, чтоб вы в эту `data` что-либо заносили. Вот нажмите `Ctrl+F`, напишите `data`, вам подсветит все то, что вы предоставили, видим в самом конце `Data.data = Console.ReadLine()`, но этот код не связан вообще каким-либо образом с `Task8`. Также есть `//  Data.data = null;`, но этот код закомментирован, выполнятся не должен.  И почему вообще все `static`? Что за каша? Вы можете сделать нормальный, минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который покажет эту проблему? Ибо сейчас вообще не понятно, почему вдруг `Data.data` должна быть у вас заполнена, в коде этого запонения нет.

Comment: У каждого процесса - своя область памяти. То, что вы подключили один проект к другому не означает, что они стали разделять общую память. В каждом процессе свой собственный экземпляр класса `Data`, с собственными полями `data` и `figures`.

Comment: Очевидно, вам нужно [Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие) - выбирайте любой подходящий способ.

Comment: Например, [How to: Use Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication)

Comment: [Memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) - если хочется именно через память работать.

Comment: Попробовал через memory-mapped files.В одном проекте создал его, записал в него массив чаров. В другом проекте открываю, но  пишет
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Unable to find the specified file."